# How orginize data saving with entoty-dto-request design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose there is an `entity` with some data. So send this data via network it is needed to transform this data in to `dto`. Dto can **not** be mapped as field to field. Also for network transmission it is needed to serizalize `dto` into bytes.

So what is the problem? The problem is I do not understant what to save in database. At first glace, only the entity should be saved. But what if there is a bug with `entity-to-dto` transforming? So it is (probably) needed to save `dto` too. Also there can be a situation when supporter from receiving system tell that transmitted data is wrong. So network bytes whould be also save in ... database. Note that bytes can not be replaced with json or xml.

As you can see saving all data (entity,dto and bytes) is too much. Also when dto is saved it should have `id` and foreign key to the entity, so ti became entity too. As a variant byte and dto can be saved to the log files and deleted later. But also storing log for log time is not best practise as I think, also searching can be a problem.

So what from entity, dto and bytes should be saved and where?

**Some notes**

Of course there can be something wrong with using designin dto, entity logging using. You can write about all prolems in answer or comments.

Comment: What if the database has a bug? You should thus need to save everything in two different databases? What if the OS has a bug? You should thus need to run the application on two different OSes, and send the same request to both? You understand this doesn't make much sense, right? So my answer to your question "*what if there is a bug with entity-to-dto transforming?*" would be: you would fix the bug.

Comment: Without sarcasm you suggest to store entity in db and no more?

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggest. You can log DTOs, bytes, or whatever if you think it's useful for debugging or for diagnosing incidents, but that's very different from storing the DTOs in the database.